# How to align table cells center left?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a simple table structure.

```css
table > tbody > tr > td{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Client</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-md-4">
            C 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="col-md-4">
            Client 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

**The question is** : How can I `align` **td**-s content `left` and `center`. ?

The output should be something like this :
[image]

Comment: using `text-align`? Or are you wanting them aligned to the center, but then left justified to the largest word?  If so, you can't use a table

Comment: Take two cells, with 50% width, but leave blank first cell and use second cell for your text.

Comment: @Pete, I want them aligned to the center, but then simply left

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Check out my answer below, I provided two solutions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting the lower cells to be left justified from the centre, then just add padding-left 50% to your body cells

```css
.table tbody td {
  padding-left: 50%;
  text-align;
  left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-4">
        C 1
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-4">
        Client 2
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you want them centred to the largest word, then left-aligned, you cannot have separate rows for the tbody, you would need to wrap all the words in an inline block div:

```css
.col-md-4 {
  text-align: center;
}

.inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Client</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col-md-4">
        <div class="inline-block">
          C 1<br> Client 2
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
td {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Client</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
            C 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
            Client 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

If you can't add extra `table-cells` you could use `padding`:

```css
.table tbody td {
  padding-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Client</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            C 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            Client 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
td {
  width: 50%;
}
td:last-child {
  border-left:1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <table class="table table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Client</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
            C 1
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
          </td>
          <td>
            Client 2
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `colspan="<number of columns to merge>"` and `rowspan="<number of rows to merge>"` to merge row or column:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">Client</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2" width="50%"></td>
        <td>
            C 1
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Client 2
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```